# How to correctly manage initialisation in constructor?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, abstraction, glew

I'm writing a simple wrapper in C++ around GLFW and OpenGL, as an exercice. I have a class `Window` and a class `Renderer`. The `Window` class owns a `Renderer` member.

`Window` sets the GLFW context in its constructor and run the main loop, and call for its `Renderer` member to draw. `Renderer` sets the buffers in its constructor, and does the OpenGL things.

The problem I've got is that OpenGL calls *require* to have an OpenGL context available. If I were to just initialise the `Renderer` before calling the constructor of `Window`, the constructor of `Renderer` would be called before the GLFW context would be created.

What I did is that I instead store a `unique_ptr` to a `Renderer` in `Window`, and I call `std::make_unique<Renderer>` in the constructor of `Window`. Then, in the destructor, I call  `std::unique_ptr::reset()` before destroying the GLFW context, so that I can make the OpenGL calls to free stuff with a still valid context.

```
class Window
{
   public:
       Window()
       {
           //initialising GLFW and creating an OpenGL context
           //...
           m_renderer = std::make_unique<Renderer>();
       }
       ~Window()
       {
           m_renderer.reset();
           glfwTerminate();
       }
       int run()
       {
           while(...)
           {
               m_renderer->draw();
               //...
           }
           return 0;
       }
   private:
       std::unique_ptr<Renderer> m_renderer; 
       //...
}

class Renderer
{
    public:
        Renderer() { //Set buffers }
        ~Renderer() { //Free buffers }
        draw() { glDrawElements(...); //... }
    private:
        //...
}

int main()
{
     Window window();
     return window->run();
}
```

I understand that object should already be initialised in the body of the constructor, which is not the case here. I feel I might have done some dependency between `Renderer` and `Window` backwards or that my general architecture is wrong. I would rather rely on the constructor and destructors being called at the right moment based on the scope and not on me manually triggering it.

What would be a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you create a separate class, call it `GLFWInit` that does the GLFW initialization and calls `glfwTerminate()` in its destructor. Then you have two options:

1. Embed an object of type `GLFWInit` in your `Window` class. Place the member early, but at the least before the `m_renderer` member.
2. Derive your `Window` class from `GLFWInit`.

Both methods ensure that GLFW is initialied before `m_renderer` and torn down after it. Then you do not even have to make the renderer a pointer and can embed the member directly (if that is feasible).

Comment: That seams doable indeed. Is that common practice?

Comment: It follows the RAII idiom. In that regard, it is common practice.